# Apache24 service is not starting

Tags: windows, apache, webserver

I downloaded httpd-2.4.26-Win64-VC15.zip from apache website and unzipped the file then i copied Apache24 folder into c drive. But when i try to start ApacheMonitor.exe i am getting an error saying :

Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified

No matter how many times i tried same error getting. please  help me regarding this issue.

[image]

Comment: May Be .. If Skype installed its take port 80 (Listens on port 80) .. Check it ?

Comment: How can i check it ?

Comment: If You Using Skype app > Then .. Inside Option > Connection

Comment: Uncheck the Use Port 80 .. From There..

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-install-apache-on-windows/